# How to connect to files in Dockerized Dagster instance?

Tags: docker, dagster

I have managed to deploy Dagster to Docker and I can load the web UI etc.

However, I am really struggling to understand how to create a development environment locally e.g access remote files.

I have tried creating a mount volume and I can SSH onto the host server but I hit permissions issues galore when trying to access the volume.

I am sure I must be missing something or doing something wrong in my approach.

I just want to create a simple data pipeline in a dockerized instance of Dagster - but cannot connect to my files to actually do the dev work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.